# Converting string/int to double in C#

Tags: c#, int, double

Here is a simple calculator, to calculate how much candy you can get when dividing the kilogram price with the money you have allocated for candy.

In example: "Candy costs 5$ a kilo. I have 3.50$ allocated for candy. I would use this program to calculate the amount of candy I get."

It works fine until using decimals. I want to convert the string to Double so I can use decimals with the calculator. 4$ kilo price and 8$ money of course results to 2 kilos of candy. But if the kilo price was 4.80$ and I had 9.30$ money, I would only get an error and cause the command prompt to crash.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      //The variables
        int int1;
        int int2;
        string text1;
        string text2;
      //The actual calculation
        System.Console.Write("Please input the kilogram price of candy: ");
        text1 = System.Console.ReadLine();
        int1 = int.Parse(text1);
        System.Console.Write("Please input the money allocated for candy ");
        text2 = System.Console.ReadLine();
        int2 = int.Parse(text2);
        System.Console.WriteLine("With the amount of money you input you would get " + (int2 / int1) + " kilos of candy.");
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Simply use Double.Parse?! (Although i would recommend using .TryParse)

Comment: Use `Double.TryParse(text1, out myDoubleVariable);` instead of using integers. Integers are, by definition, whole numbers.

Comment: why `int` not `double`? ps. `int1` is a terrible variable name :p

Comment: Is your question _"Why can't I store `4.80` in an `int`"_? Maybe you need to educate yourself about the [various numeric variable types C# offers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s1ax56ch.aspx).

Comment: Why not use `decimal` instead?  It's better suited for cases like this.

Comment: Also, you didn't _even_ provide your error message. Please read [FAQ] and [ask] couple of times..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're using `int` variable types, which can only contain [integer numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer), i.e. "whole" numbers without decimals, such as `1` and `42`. As soon as you want to use decimals, you'll need a variable type that can support this.

C# has a few of those built in: `float`, `double` and `decimal`. Given you're working with monetary data, where precision and accuracy are very important, you must use `decimal`.

You also want to use the `bool`-returning `TryParse()` as opposed to the exception-throwing `Parse()` method.

So change your code to use `decimal` and `decimal.TryParse()`:

```
decimal pricePerKilogram;
string input = Console.ReadLine();

if (!decimal.TryParse(input, out pricePerKilogram))
{
    // show error or retry
}
```

Comment: Small addition, it would be better to use an `IFormatProvider` (like `InvariantCulture`) in `TryParse` to specify this `.` as a `NumberDecimalSeparator`.

Comment: This answer was the most comprehensive and helped me. I am obviously a beginner on C# and somehow I can't assimilate the variable types yet. I'm sure I will in the future as I get going with this language. Thanks! @CodeCaster

Answer (score 3):

You need to parse your inputs from `decimal`, not `int`.  Here, try it this way:

```
System.Console.Write("Please input the kilogram price of candy: ");
decimal pricePerKilo = decimal.Parse(System.Console.ReadLine());
System.Console.Write("Please input the money allocated for candy ");
decimal amountAllocatedForCandy = decimal.Parse(System.Console.ReadLine());
System.Console.WriteLine("With the amount of money you input you would get " + (amountAllocatedForCandy / pricePerKilo) + " kilos of candy.");
System.Console.Read();
```

An `int` is a type that can only store whole numbers -- i.e. no fractional component/decimal digits -- which is why you got an error when you tried to parse a string number with decimal digits into an `int`.  A `decimal`, on the other hand, is used to store numbers with fractional components.

Each type has its uses: you would never want to store, say, number of candy pieces using a `decimal` since that can only be a whole number.  Doing so could lead to unnecessary confusion for future maintainers of your code and could lead to bugs that are hard to find.

Comment: In normal circumstances I think using `var` almost everywhere is fine, but when OP clearly doesn't know the difference between even the most basic data types, you probably shouldn't use it.

Answer (score 1):

that is because 4.80 or 9.30 is not integer.

```
   double double1;
    double double2;
    string text1;
    string text2;
  //The actual calculation
    System.Console.Write("Please input the kilogram price of candy: ");
    text1 = System.Console.ReadLine();
    double1 = double.Parse(text1);
    System.Console.Write("Please input the money allocated for candy ");
    text2 = System.Console.ReadLine();
    double2 = double.Parse(text2);
    System.Console.WriteLine("With the amount of money you input you would get " + (double2 / double1) + " kilos of candy.");
```

NOTE: INT stores integer value like 1 2 3 4 etc...

Comment: Don't use `double` for monetary data.

Comment: You answer is very bad advice! Never use `double` for something that needs to be precise!

Answer (score 1):

As to your question:

Just use <s>doubles</s> **decimals** in the first place!

```
decimal price;
decimal allowance;
```

Also, some additional unsolicited advice:

You've got a few issues here.

First of all, you'll need to swap your division in the `WriteLine` statement to get the correct calculation.

Also, I'd recommend renaming your variables to something more descriptive.

Here's your code with some modifications. I've commented each change.

```
//The variables
    decimal price; //CHANGE: descriptive variables!
    decimal allowance;
    string priceInput;
    string allowanceInput;
//The actual calculation
    System.Console.Write("Please input the kilogram price of candy: ");
    priceInput = System.Console.ReadLine();
    price = decimal.Parse(priceInput); //CHANGE: use double.Parse here instead of int.Parse
    System.Console.Write("Please input the money allocated for candy ");
    allowanceInput = System.Console.ReadLine();
    allowance = decimal.Parse(allowanceInput); //CHANGE: use double.Parse here instead of int.Parse
    System.Console.WriteLine("With the amount of money you input you would get "
        + Math.Round(allowance / price, 2) + " kilos of candy.");
    //CHANGE: Divide the money you have by the amount it costs to get the KG of candy.
```

EDIT: Added decimals due to working with money.

Comment: Your edit is not helpful.  It doesn't explain why.  Best to just leave it out and remove all references to double, using decimal instead.